# Getting number of rows for each group

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a query over two tables:

`locations (user, longitude, latitude, name, description, date)`

`visits (user, longitude, latitude, visit_time)`

In order to get list of locations that user have visited in the last `x` days, with count of total visits for each location.

I try to JOIN these columns and group the results by `longitude` and `latitude`:

```
$dCntMS = $dCnt * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
$currentTimeMS = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
$x = $currentTimeMS - $dCntMS;

$query = "SELECT `locations`.`latitude`, `locations`.`longitude`, `locations`.`name`, `locations`.`description`, `locations`.`date`" . 
         "FROM `locations`, `visits` " . 
         "WHERE `visits`.`user`='$user' " .
             "AND `visits`.`longitude`=`locations`.`longitude` " .
             "AND `visits`.`latitude`=`locations`.`latitude` " . 
             "AND `visits`.`visit_time` >= '$x'" .
        "GROUP BY `longitude`, `latitude`";
```

Which returns unique locations that user have visited in a given time, something like this:

```
[0] => (
        [latitude] => 42.8903888
        [longitude] => 21.8133837
        [name] => locationName
        [description] => shortLocationDesc
        [date] => 13913465172
       )
[1] => (...)
```

**But I need to have one more column in the result set. 
Like this one :**

```
    (
        [latitude] => 42.8903888
        [longitude] => 21.8133837
        [name] => locationName
        [description] => shortLocationDesc
        [date] => 13913465172
        [totalVisits] => 5
    )
```

In other words, to retrieve the number of rows in each group.

I believe I need `COUNT` function in `SELECT`, but since each location is identified by two attributes (`longitude` and `latitude`) I don't know what would be the right way of doing this.

I appreciate any help.

**UPDATE**

Thank you all @Iqbal, @Barmar, @Strawberry for your help!

Comment: What's the problem? It counts by whatever set of columns you're grouping on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you can also write Barmar's query this way. I think it looks nicer...

```
$query = "
SELECT l.latitude
     , l.longitude
     , l.name
     , l.description
     , l.date
     , COUNT(*) totalVisits
  FROM locations l 
  JOIN visits v 
    ON v.longitude = l.longitude 
   AND v.latitude = l.latitude 
 WHERE v.user = '$user' 
   AND v.visit_time >= '$x' 
 GROUP 
    BY longitude, latitude;
";
```

Comment: So, I dont understand why adding `COUNT(*) totalVisits` to my original query didnt run...any thoughts?

Comment: Only the query given in the question is relevant to this, no other code.

Comment: No, no, no, before asking this question I tried to add `Count(*)` to my query (the one from the question), similar to Barmar's first  approach, but that didnt run. The only change I see between that query and the one you provided is..well, using aliases. Or am I missing something?

Comment: There's no reason why adding `COUNT(*)` to your original query shouldn't have worked. You probably had a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT `locations`.`latitude`, `locations`.`longitude`, MAX(`locations`.`name`),  count(*) AS TotalVisits" . 
     "FROM `locations`, `visits` " . 
     "WHERE `visits`.`user`='$user' " .
         "AND `visits`.`longitude`=`locations`.`longitude` " .
         "AND `visits`.`latitude`=`locations`.`latitude` " . 
         "AND `visits`.`visit_time` >= '$x'" .
    "GROUP BY `longitude`, `latitude`";
```

Comment: I don't think you can put a table name before a function call like that.

Comment: @Barmar You are right, I did mistake. Updated it now.

Comment: @earthless what is the result? Error or invalid count?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT l.latitude, l.longitude, l.name," .
         "       l.description, l.date, COUNT(*) AS totalVisits" . 
         "FROM locations AS l " . 
         "INNER JOIN visits AS v ON v.longitude = l.longitude AND v.latitude = l.latitude " .
         "WHERE v.user='$user' " .
         "AND v.visit_time >= '$x' " .
         "GROUP BY longitude, latitude";
```

The `COUNT(*)` function counts the rows in each group specified by the `GROUP BY` columns.

Comment: I c/p this query as is, wont run.

Comment: @earthless we don't have a diagnostic for "won't run".

Comment: I changed the query to use my `v` alias in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I am sorry. Query wont run. 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`locations`, `visits` WHERE `visits`.`user`='johndoe' AND `visits`.`longitude`=`l' at line 1

Comment: And for the edited version:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`locations` AS l INNER JOIN visits AS v ON v.longitude = l.longitude AND v.latit' at line 1

Comment: Change all the `locations.` to `l.`